# Using different EPSG in QGIS projects

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg, qgz

I have 2 projects, with data from different regions and with different EPSG, 1 with EPSG 31983 and the other with EPSG 31984, according to the folder structure shown below, in Windows explorer.

[image]

[image]

In both projects I have the same folder structure and file names. I created a QGZ project in QGIS 3.12, using project data 01 (EPSG 31983), included the data (vector and raster), defined the project's symbology and visual coordinate system as being EPSG 4674 (figure below).

[image]

I saved the project with the name “Project.qgz”). I went back to Windows explorer and copied the QGZ to project 2 folder (EPSG 31984) Crtl + c / Crtl + v.

[image]

I opened QGIS again, now choosing the QGZ project that I previously copied into the folders of project 2 (EPSG 31984) The project opened normally, however when reading the two themes QGIS kept the EPSG of the previous themes (project 1), or that is, he fetched the data correctly, applied the symbology but kept EPSG 31983 for project 1 not updating to EPSG 31984 for project 2.

[image]

[image]

I need to apply this example to several projects, just by copying and pasting the “.QGZ” from one folder to another.

How do I get QGIS to automatically update the EPSG of the data being presented, in the same way as it updates the symbology for the new data being loaded?

---

The shapefile file inside the folder 'Project EPSG 31984' is set to EPSG: 31984. I checked it. I am referring to CRS. The problem is that QGIS is memorizing the EPSG of the shapefile within the QGZ project, and then, when I make a copy of the QGZ project (copy / paste) to the other project, QGIS does not change the EPSG when reading the new shapefile. 
I am trying to show that when copying the .QGZ project from one folder to another, QGIS updates all data to contain the shapefiles in the new folder, however, it does not update the coordinate systems (CRS), causing problems.
There any suggestion to solve this?

Comment: The shapefile in the _'Project EPSG 31984'_ folder seems to be defined in `EPSG:31983` CRS. When you say _"with data from different regions and with different EPSG"_ , are you referring to the CRS of the data or the name of the folder?

Comment: Gabriel. I completed the text.

Comment: I don't think I was able to explain my doubt properly. I think it may be a problem in reading the data in Qgis.
Other example: I have a shapefile with the name “Diques.shp” it has an EPSG 32721 mapping system.
I enter QGIS 3.12, add this shapefile, save the project with the name “teste.qgz”
I right click on the shapefile “Diques.shp” and I export it to EPSG 32722 with the name “Diques2.shp”.

Comment: I exit QGIS, delete the file "Diques.shp" and rename the file "Diques2.shp" to "Diques.shp", that is, I replace the original shapefile in EPSG 32721 for the shapefile EPSG 32722.
I enter QGIS again and open the “teste.qgz” project. I open the Properties menu, "Source" option of the “Diques.shp” layer.
My expectation was that QGIS, when reading the “Diques.shp” layer, would update to EPSG 32722. But it maintains EPSG 32721.

Comment: A shapefile is not a _.shp_ file. The projection of a shapefile is on a _.prj_ file, so if the _Diques.prj_ file says `EPSG:32721`, the _Diques_ shapefile is in `EPSG:32721`. Also, I'm not sure, but I think that QGIS write another file with the projection to not use the ESRI WKT definition stored in a _.prj_ file. Try to find information about that to use shapefiles in QGIS, or use GeoPackage layers.

Comment: Gabriel, I know that shapefile is composed of several files ( p. ex. shp, prj, sbn, shx, dbf, etc.) I tend to explain that Qgis is not updating the EPSG when I do the tests mentioned above. Do you have some ideia if is a problem?

Comment: Denilson, I was trying to say that deleting _.shp_ file and replacing with other you are not replacing the shapefile, you are corrupting it instead. If all the data has the same structure, it will be usable, but you are not changing the projection of the shapefile, because the projection is stored in the _.prj_ file of the shapefile. Also, maybe QGIS is reading it from another file. If you want to continue working with shapefiles, the way to work with them is deleting all _Diques.*_ files from one folder and replacing them with all _Diques.*_ files from the other, that is the shapefile

Comment: `delete the file "Diques.shp" and rename the file "Diques2.shp" to "Diques.shp", that is, I replace the original shapefile in EPSG 32721 for the shapefile EPSG 32722`, thats just not true.

Comment: Yes, I did that. I delete the file "Diques.*" and rename the file "Diques2.* " to "Diques.*".     I exited from QGIS, delete the file "Diques.*" and rename the file "Diques2.*" to "Diques.*", that is, I replaced the original shapefile in EPSG 32721 for the shapefile EPSG 32722. I enter QGIS again and open the “teste.qgz” project. I open the Properties menu, "Source" option of the “Diques” layer. My expectation was that QGIS, when reading the “Diques” layer, would update to EPSG 32722. But it maintains EPSG 32721.